# I get the error "cannot start compilation" after adding a new module to my CorDapp project

Tags: corda

Having added a new module to my CorDapp project, I get the following error when I try and compile the project:

> Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module "bot". Specify the output path in the Project Structure dialog.

I don't see an output path specified for any of the other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your new module to the

> settings.gradle

file in the root of your project.